# Positive recurrent, zero recurrent and transient states

Tags: self-learning, markov-chains

How do we prove that a state in a Markov chain process is positive recurrent, zero recurrent or transient? For example, if we have a transition matrix

$$P=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \ 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
  0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
  \frac{1}{2} & \ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} 
  \end{array}\right)$$

how do we do it??

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you know the definition of positive recurrence, etc?

Comment: I know the formulas but i d not know how to use them.. :/

Comment: If i have only the matrix i can find them without using anything else?

Comment: You need to construct a set of recurrent equations (three in this case) to find stationary distribution. Can you do this?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you show me how to make it ..

Comment: It will help if we find the stationary distributions?

Comment: hold on, how many states do you have? If there are $4$ states, you need a $4 \times 4$ transition matrix $P$

Comment: I just make that matrix up to see how we have to work,i will add one more!

Comment: That is ok,right?

Comment: "Formulas", to define positive recurrence? Hmmm... not really.

Comment: @Did i have searched my notes and only mathematical formulas i saw..thats why i was confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the state space is **finite**, start by dividing the state space into [communicating classes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Reducibility)

Now check each class:

- If it is possible to leave the class, then all states in that 
  class are transient.

  If it is not possible to leave the class, then all states in that class are positive recurrent.

There are no null recurrent states.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!!So the only thing that matters is the classes!!Now it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

The path $1\to4\to2\to3\to1$ enumerates the state space and has positive probability hence every state is positive recurrent.

Comment: ok that was easy but how we come up with the other terms?

Comment: Define other terms.

Comment: To see if i get it so far.To be positive recurrent we have to see if starting from a position A we have to able to pass through all the states of the matrix??and by other terms i meant zero recurrent (ok it will be the states that are no positive recurrent) and transient

Comment: Sorry but I am seeing no clearcut definition here...

Comment: for example this is not positive recurrent              \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \ 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \ 0 &\frac{1}{4} \\
  0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \ 0 & \ 0\\
  \ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \ 0\\
  \frac{1}{2} & \ 0 & \ 0 & \ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \ 0\\
  \ 0 & \ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \ 0& \frac{1}{2} & \ 0 \\
  \ 0 & \ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \ 0 & \frac {1}{3}
  \end{array}